# CLR C++ DLL project can not be opened in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019

A couple of years ago, I wanted to add some open source C++ code to my C# project.

The C++ author, though a briliant physicist was a horrible programmer, and rewriting it into C# was proving very difficult.  My solution at the time was to make a CLR DLL with the C++ code with a little extra code to convert to/from C# data types.

Problem solved.  My C# program uses the CLR dll file and all is well.

Fast Forward to 2020 and I am considering upgrading from using Visual Studio 2015 to using Visual Studio 2017.

When I open the CLR DLL project I get an error:
The main  .h file which was long ago created by Visual Studio and modified by me, will not even be displayed.

Has visual studio 2019 dropped support for creating and using C++ CLR DLL ?

Comment: You get an error... Any chance you tell us which one?

Comment: The error only happened once - complaining about MFC.

Answer (score 0):

Seems Visual Studio automatically commented out some of my include statements which I had written which contained the letters mfsk

Problem solved.